# Why tf.placeholder returns serialized example(s)?

Tags: tensorflow

I’m reading [mnist_saved_model.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py)

At line 62~64, [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) returns serialized example. And [`tf.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example) function uses it like this,

```
serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example’)
feature_configs = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature(shape=[784], dtype=tf.float32),}
tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
```

I knew `placeholder` returns a Tensor. Then, what exactly ‘serialized tf.Example’ means?

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.placeholder`](https://web.archive.org/web/20190503065922/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder)s can be used as entry points to you model for different kinds of data. For example, you could use `x = tf.placeholder(shape=[784], dtype=tf.float32)`, which is suitable for feeding NumPy arrays with shape `[784]` and type float.

In your example, the placeholder should be fed with a `string` type. This is useful if you obtain your data directly from a text file or from a [TFRecord](https://web.archive.org/web/20190524131218/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TFRecordReader) / [protobuf](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) (which is a format for serializing your data). (To obtain the string from a protobuf, you can use [`tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180909065533/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/python_io/tf_record_iterator). You can also use the [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) API).

When you obtain the string from a TFRecord file, it is a serialized representation of your example. You now want to parse it into a `tf.Tensor`. This is done using [`tf.parse_example`](https://web.archive.org/web/20180909061658/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example). The `feature_configs` dictionary specifies how to parse the data from the string.

(Note: `tf.parse_example` does not actually parse anything - it only adds an operation to the computational graph that can perform parsing. The parsing itself will occur when you run the graph, using `sess.run(...)`)

The tensor, after parsing, is `tf_example['x']`.

---

**EDIT:**

To elaborate some more, as a response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444555/why-tf-placeholder-returns-serialized-examples/49471351?noredirect=1#comment89026954_49471351): In your example, `serialized_tf_example` is a `tf.Tensor` (as can be verified by running `type(serialized_tf_example)`). Its data type are strings (as can be verified by running `serialized_tf_example.dtype`). As with all tensors, this means that you can feed it any multidimensional array of its data type (which is strings). (If in the `tf.placeholder()` call you would have given a value to the `shape` argument, that would force you to use a specific shape for the multidimensional array). So, for example, these are valid calls:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(serialized_tf_example, feed_dict={serialized_tf_example:'abc'})
sess.run(serialized_tf_example, feed_dict={serialized_tf_example:[['some','strings'],['in an','array']]})
```

This tensor instance is named `serialized_example`, since its purpose is to be fed with a serialized encoding of the example that is going to be processed. This tensor is then converted from this encoding to a numerical multidimensional array, using `tf.parse_example()`

Comment: Then you mean, ‘a serialized example’ is NOT a tensor. right? But does the placeholder returns a tensor, doesn’t it?